# my web page refuse loading after i added a particular function how can i resolve it

Tags: javascript, html

My web page refuse loading after i added this  function `function last(){ for(l=1;i<transfer_1;l++){list[l]=list[arrangelist]; arrangelist++;}`.Am trying to insert a number at the front of the array by changing the index of the recent entry (1,2,3,4) using just one Array.If i take out that function the whole code runs fine,but immediately i call that function my web page(chrome) load for enternity.I tried browser but not showing any thing.

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>   
    <script>
        let num=0;
        let k=0;
        let list =new Array(1,2,3,4);
        let transfer_1=0;
        let arrangelist=transfer_1;
     function mylength(){
        for(i in list){
           num++;
        }
        return num;
          }
    //length of arrayfunction
    function fun(chilen){   
        this.chilen=chilen
    }
    mylength();
    var mainlist=new fun(num);
    const fixed=mainlist.chilen;
    transfer_1=fixed+transfer_1;

    function insert_infront(insert){
        for(j=mainlist.chilen;j<mainlist.chilen+mainlist.chilen;j++){ 
            list[j]=list[k];
            k++;
        }
        list[0]=insert;

    }

    function last(){
         for(l=1;i<transfer_1;l++){
       list[l]=list[arrangelist];
       arrangelist++;
        }
    }
let l=prompt("enter that should be insert in front");
insert_infront(l);
alert(transfer_1)
last();
document.write(list);
   </script> 


</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it had many problems, the most important of which is you didn't wait for the document to load and immediately executed the script, I hope this is very clear what I did here. It is more readable and uses less code.

Another thing I'd like to mention is I made it simply append the list tag with the value there are obviously many way you can add them to your document or simply displaying the full array. But that's up to you.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      let arr = [1,2,3,4]
      const value = prompt("Enter value to inset in front")
      value && arr.unshift(value)
      let el = document.getElementById("root")
      arr.map(item => {
        const child = `<li>${item}</li>`
        el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', child)
      })
    }
  </script>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Am trying to do that work with out using any inbuilt property or method  like append etc .

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do that, I personally have never tried it, however if that's the case then you need to look into dom api's and try to mimic the way they do it in those built in functions. That's the only way I can think of it, my advice, use what you have.